# Does the new Windows 8 Burmese/Myanmar work properly in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, fonts, keyboard-layout, language

I just learned from Michael Kaplan's Microsoft internationalization blog, *Sorting it all Out*, that Windows 8 now includes a keyboard layout form the Burmese / Myanmar language and also a very nice looking Burmese / Myanmar font.

[image: Windows 8 Burmese / Myanmar option]

I know the Burmese / Myanmar writing system is of similar complexity to Khmer and Tibetan with challenges such as vertically stacking marks, differing logical and visual ordering of codepoints and glyphs, contextual glyph shaping, etc.

Often for a font to work well in a given OS the OS's rendering system (Uniscribe in the case of Windows) needs to specifically support the script / writing system. This is especially true if the script uses OpenType / FreeType features uncommon in previous scripts and/or fonts.

So does this new Windows 8 Burmese font work fully or partially on Windows 7? Does it require a newer Uniscribe version and if so does the Windows 8 Uniscribe work on Windows 7?

Comment: No, this very specific Windows 8 feature is not supported in Windows 7.

Comment: Sorry @Ramhound (and your upvoter) but Ahmad Quresh has an answer which disagrees with you, and also provides some details. Do you have some details to add to back up your assertion that it doesn't work? (I currently don't have a way to test it independently.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this Burmese font works on Windows - Vista and 7 too.This font is same or may be clone to Padauk font of SIL.org.

For XP and below, OS should have Uniscribe version 1.609.5219.0 469 KiB (2005-08-17) or above.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question Ahmad! It would be a really great answer if you could include a screenshot of this font under Windows Vista or 7 (-;

Comment: just curious, if you know the language enough that you can tell if the font works, why not try it?

Answer (score 0):

No. The MyanmarText font doesn't work below Windows8. It does require new Uniscribe engine. Replacing usp10.dll file doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Lionslayer. In what way does it not work? Error message? Garbled font rendering? I'm trying to establish which of these conflicting answers is right.